# Why I am not able to see the version of maven in command prompt?

Tags: maven

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgniz.png)
The following statement is displayed when running the command mvn -v
Have tried reinstalling maven
Environmental variables are all fine
Any other alternatives to resolve this problem will encouraged
java version in my system is 17.0